# Extract Info from file by maches text

Tags: php, regex

I have a php file, in this file i have some data lets say

```
<This is the content of the text file>

"dim://realthings1/true"
"rel://stop1"
"dim://realthings2/false"
"rel://stop2"
"dim://realthings3/false"
"rel://stop3"
"dim://realthings4/false"
"rel://stop4"

<This is the rest of content>
```

I need a php code to extract and echo the first "dim://realthings1/true" result `dim://realthings1/true`
but this "dim://......." data is changing every 1 houre 
how to extract data from there whith a php code thats extract first value of "dim://......"

I tried

```
<?php 
$Text=file_get_contents("test.php");
preg_match('/dim\s*:\s*\'([^\']+)\'/',$Text,$Match)
echo $Match[1] ."\n";
?>
```

this code works fine whith this data

> dim: 'realthings1'

I've tried to change this code whith no result!
Please Help!

Comment: may be this is what you want `preg_match('/dim\s*:\s*([^\']+)/',$Text,$Match)`

Comment: it is ok but the echo is not its echo everithig there after "dim:"
`//realthings1/true""rel://stop1""dim://realthings2/false""rel://stop2""dim://realthings3/false""rel://stop3""dim://realthings4/false""rel://stop4"` i need only `//realthings1/true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want only that line you can use the UN-greedy flag `U`

```
$Text=file_get_contents("test.php");
$Match=array();
if (preg_match('/dim\s*:\s*([^\']+)[\'"]/U',$Text,$Match)){
    echo $Match[1];
}
```

For all Matches

```
$Text=file_get_contents("test.php");
$Match=array();
if (preg_match_all('/dim\s*:\s*([^\']+)[\'"]/U',$Text,$Match)){
    print_r($Match[1]);
}
```

The following will match anything starting with `dim` followed by 0 or more spaces then : then 0 or more spaces anything (which is not ' or " or space) then ' or " or space. and be UN-greedy. the item matched inside the bracket is what you get in `$Matches[1]`. hope it is clear now

```
/dim\s*:\s*([^\'"\s]+)[\'"\s]/U
```

Comment: it's ok but  how to echo just the de second dim://

Comment: if you use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match` then `$Matches[1]` will be and array of all the matches.

Comment: cant i ad a "space" delimiter to `('/dim\s*:\s*([^\']+)`[\'"]/U',$Text,$Match)). let say i have`"dim://transfer/true 'here is space'retry"` but i need echo only `//transfer/true`

Comment: sure you can `/dim\s*:\s*([^\']+)[\'"\s]/U` but `dim://real things1/true` will be matched as `//real` note a space between `real` and `things1`